# Error exportando clase en TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, poo

Tengo un par de clases en el ficher clases.ts y en el archivo main.ts importo una de ellas para probarla, pero cuando lo paso a JS y lo ejecuto, simplemente me sale el error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Aqui esta la clase que importo:

```
export class Coche {
    public color: string; //Valores predeterminados de la clase
    public modelo: string;
    public marca: string;
    private precio: number;

    constructor(
        color: string = "negro",
        modelo: string = "desconocido",
        marca: string = "desconocido",
        precio: number = 0
    ) {
        this.color = color;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
```

Y aqui está el fichero main.ts

```
import { Coche } from "./clases";

class Main {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Aplicacion cargada");
    }
}

var main = new Main();
```

No he echo nada y me da error en la linea 3 de clase.js.
Realmente necesito resolver esto, para continuar con mi curso, asi que agradeceria mucho si alguien me dice que está mal.

Aqui el JS que da el error, justo en las dos primeras lineas, en alguna parte. "exports" supuestamente no está definido o algo asi.

```
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.Coche = void 0;
var Camiseta = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Camiseta() {
    }
    //El estatus de cada parametro puede ser public, protected o private
    Camiseta.prototype.setPrecio = function (precio) {
        if (precio === void 0) { precio = 0; }
        //metodo publico
        this.precio = precio; //accede a la variable color de la clases
    };
    Camiseta.prototype.getPrecio = function () {
        return this.precio;
    };
    return Camiseta;
}());
```

Aqui mi tsconfig.json, tal cual se creó:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                                   /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                             /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */
    // "declaration": true,                         /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                      /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                           /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                             /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                             /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                           /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                     /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                              /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                       /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                     /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                    /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                 /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                 /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,        /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                      /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                      /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                   /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,          /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,            /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                  /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an 'override' modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,  /* Require undeclared properties from index signatures to use element accesses. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                 /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                              /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                             /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                                 /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                    /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                            /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                               /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                     /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                       /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

A continuacion el archivo html desde donde se ejecuta el programa:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Clases en TS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="clases.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Curso de JavaScript</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías compartir ¿cómo estás haciendo la transpilación por favor? La cosa podría estar en tu archivo tsconfig.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia. A q te refieres con el tsconfig? Y donde lo busco?

Comment: Más fácil, ¿cómo le haces para pasar de Typescript a Javascript? Supongo que usas `tsc`. Lo común es que en la raíz de tu proyecto exista un archivo *tsconfig.json*, en este archivo existen reglas que determinan cómo `tsc` pasará (transpilará) de TS a JS.

Comment: Si, uso tsc. Solo hay una carpeta node_modules y package-lock.json en el diretorio del proyecto.

Comment: Comparte porfavor el comando completo que utilizas.

Comment: Ahi está el archivo que dijiste. Aun no lo he tocado.

Comment: He ejecutado el código de forma satisfactoria con tu configuración de TS. Según ví, es la configuración que te da por defecto al inicializar el proyecto. Lo único que me faltaría por ver es el comando que utilizas para ejecutar tu proyecto, ¿lo haces directamente con node o utilizas un script de npm? Cualquiera que fuera el caso, sería de mucha utilidad que compatieras el comando que utilizas.

Comment: Uso Node y en consola el comando tsc con el archivo .ts que quiero ejecutar. Como en "tsc archivo.ts"

Comment: ¿Y luego cómo ejecutas el archivo .js que se genera? Lo ideal sería transpilar todo el proyecto, no solo un archivo. Noté que yo obtengo un .js distinto al tuyo y pudiera ser por esa razón.

Comment: Puede ser. Ejecuto el archivo .html ligado al .js que es transpilado del ts.

Comment: Pues hay una configuración que te podría servir para ejecutarlo desde un HTML solo que no recuerdo cuál es. Es un dato interesante que si lo hubieras comentando desde el inicio hubiera ahorrado varios comentarios. Si puedes [edit] tu pregunta nuevamente para incluir este tema del HTML sería genial. Recuerda que hasta el más mínimo detalle puede ser de bastante utilidad.

Comment: Ya coloqué el archivo html desde donde se ejecuta el programa.